# Model for confirmations in MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement where someone has to update a Start Date of a period for a payment. If they change it, I need to check if there are any transactions outside of that period. If there are I need to popup a confirmation, saying "Are you sure you want to change this date to the 13th of July, 2014. There are currently 18 transactions before this date that will be deleted."

How do I handle this as far as a pattern goes? At the moment, all my MVC application controllers have a 'Get' and 'Save' controller method. Like, '`Transaction(int accountID)`' to get, and '`Transactions(TransactionModel model)` on Save. But with a confirmation, I need ANOTHER controller method?

What's the standard for doing tis sort of confirmation? Adding '`ConfirmTransaction(TransactionModel model)`' that gets called if a confirmation is required?

Additionally, I'd like the same view to be used.. using a Modal Popup to handle the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can to it like this:

When the user submits the form, you stop the post, and make an ajax request to an action, look at the date field and do some calculations like those you mention, then that action will return the data to display in the modal. When you receive the ajax result, you can show the modal, if the user clicks ok, then you submit the form.

Comment: Sounds promising. Can you tell me an example way of how to stop the post? Is this all done in the controller, or is it using javacript on the view?

Comment: @Craig using JS you can attach a handler to the button's click and using `preventDefault` function you can stop the post.